# FHIR: get all active Encounter resources for any Location that is recursively "part-of" a given Location to any depth

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'd like to find a list of Encounters at, say, a given hospital, but where the Encounter's "location" reference may point to just a ward Location within that hospital, or even a just a bed on a ward in that hospital.

In either case, one could "_revinclude" the hospital using:

`Encounter?_include=Encounter:location&_revinclude:iterate=Location:partof`

Similarly, one could retrieve Encounter resources at a known depth using:

`Encounter?location.partof=Location/{{hospital id}}`

But how would I go about filtering this, within the same query, such that the only Encounters returned are those at locations that are, to any depth, "partof" a hospital with a known "id"?

The Encounter needs to be the focal resource, because it is being filtered by other properties too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server you are hitting supports it, you can use the `below` modifier to get all locations that are part of another one (see [Searching Hierarchies](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#recursive)).  In that case, your search would look something like:

`Encounter?location:below=Location/{hospital location id}&_include=Encounter:location`

If the server does not support that modifier, I am not sure you will be able to get everything in a single query.